# PHP docBlock @return className

Tags: php, netbeans, phpdoc

How do I create a PHP DocBlock stating an @return which states the return of a class. This is at the moment fairly simple by doing

```php
/**
* This returns an object of the "User" class
* @return User
*/
public function getUser() { return $this->user; }
```

I use this to get intellisense through my IDE for these return values. (in my case Netbeans)

However I have a class that returns a class based on a variable name. (for example:)

```php
/**
* This returns an object of the $param
* @param String $className
* @return ???
*/
public function getSomeObject($className) { return new $className(); }
```

and I'm trying to create intellisense for this aswell but I'm not sure if this is actually possible.

For example when I call

```php
$someClass = new MyClass();
$var = $someClass->getSomeObject('Address');
```

I would like my IDE to show me intellisense for the variable $var(which will contain an Object of Address)

Comment: What's intelissense ? What does it displays and what do you want it to display ?

Comment: Intelissense is the possibility of an IDE to show autocompletion & more information about certain functions, classes etc.. ![Screenshot](http://oi42.tinypic.com/6gj413.jpg)

Comment: You should specify what IDE it is, and tag accordingly, in the hope of an answer. But it doesn't seem possible to know that an Address is will be returned without actually evaluating 'Address' ... So if there is a feature for that, it's IDE specific, not phpdoc related.

Answer (score 2):

It would make sense to mention that the method returns an object as such:

```
/**
* [...]
* @return object
*/
```

Eventually with some details as such:

```
* @return object Object of class $className
```

See the [docs for @return](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.return.pkg.html).

Comment: Or more specifically a Subclass of a specific Superclass ie: `@return Person` and it will actually return `Employee` or `Musician` or `Sportsman`, classes that extend (inherit) `Person`.

Comment: Thanks.
However I'm now trying to get intelissense for the $className once I use the result of that method. (I amended my question to clarify)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can list *all* the potential return types,

```
@return User|Address|Sandwich|Coiture
```

, ***and*** the IDE be capable of allowing autocompletion to *aggregate* **all** methods/properties from *that entire list of classes*, then I don't see it as possible.